# Adding data to columns in a dataframe based on condition on column values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input dataframe with a column B with multiple values:
df1

```
    A   B         C D   E
0   a1  b1       c1 d3  e1
1   a1  b2,b3    c2 d4  e2
2   a2  b3       c3 d5  e3
3   a2  b2       c8 d6  e1
4   a2  b4,b1,b5 c4 d7  e2
5   a3  b4       c5 d3  e4
6   a4  b5       c6 d1  e5
7   a4  b6, b2   c1 d2  e1
8   a5  b6       c2 d7  e2
```

There is another dataframe that I want data from columns C and D in df1 added to. In this the column of B has only 1 value in each row.
df2

```
    A   B
0   a1  b1
1   a4  b6
2   a2  b1
3   a4  b2
```

I want an output dataframe that checks the row in df1 which has both the values of A and B in df2 and adds value of C and D from that row in df1.
desired output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   a1  b1  c1  d3
1   a4  b6  c1  d2
2   a2  b1  c4  d7
3   a4  b2  c1  d2
```

The challenge for me is the multiple values in column B of df1 and checking 2 columns in df1 to add C and D in df2. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it just a join?

Comment: Not exactly. e.g. for df2 row a2 b1 we also need to search in the column B list in the relevant df1 row where column A= a2 and column B= b4,b1,b5. Since b1 is present The col C and D values are then picked as c1 and d2.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to explode the column B such as you have a single value and not comma separated values in a single cell. Use `str.split` and `explode` the column B to do the operation. Then `merge`.

```
res = (
    df2.merge(df1.assign(B=lambda x: x['B'].str.split(','))
                 .explode('B')
                 [['A','B','C','D']], 
              on=['A','B'], how='left')
)
print(res)
    A   B   C   D
0  a1  b1  c1  d3
1  a4  b6  c1  d2
2  a2  b1  c4  d7
3  a4  b2  c1  d2
```

Comment: why lambda when you can assign directly? i.e `df1.assign(B=df1['B'].str.split(','))`

Comment: @AnuragDabas I think it is more a habit than anything else. You are right, one can use `df1['B']` in this case instead of lambda

Comment: Getting this error when I use for my dataset: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression   I am using this - '''
result_df = (
    merge_notin_cppgear.merge(ppr_prm_peer_review_doccodes1.assign('All Projects IDs'=ppr_prm_peer_review_doccodes1['All Projects IDs'].str.split(',')).explode('All Projects IDs')
                              [['DOC CODE','All Projects IDs','Primary Author\nLast name, First name','NEW_Author_Practice','NEW_Author_Team']],
                              on=['DOC CODE','All Projects IDs'], how='left')
)'''

Comment: @ShraddhaAvasthy it is because you can't use a string (`'All Projects IDs'`) as the name here, in my code I use directly `B` without `'` around. that said, with space in the name is not possible this way.  Try with dictionary like `.assign(**{'B':lambda x: x['B'].str.split(',')})` in this style you'll be able to use `'All Projects IDs'` as key

Comment: I now get "Syntaxerror: invalid syntax"                                                                
result_df = (merge_notin_cppgear.merge(ppr_prm_peer_review_doccodes1.assign(**{'All Projects IDs'=lambda x: x['All Projects IDs'].str.split('; ')}).explode('All Projects IDs')
                              [['DOC CODE','All Projects IDs','Primary Author\nLast name, First name','NEW_Author_Practice','NEW_Author_Team']],
                              on=['DOC CODE','All Projects IDs'], how='left'))

Comment: @ShraddhaAvasthy in the dictionary in assign, it is `:` and not `=` like `**{'All Projects IDs': lambda x: x['All...`